# Shorter way to convert array to Set when chaining without custom functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider this chain of methods that manipulates the array and results in a set:

```
[...Array(20).keys()]
  .filter(j => j % 3)
  .map(j => j * 5)
  .reduce((j, k) => { j.add(k); return j }, new Set())
==>
Set { 5, 10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70, 80, 85, 95 }
```

I know this can be rewritten by wrapping the chain:

```
new Set([...Array(20).keys()]
  .filter(j => j % 3)
  .map(j => j * 5))
==>
Set { 5, 10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70, 80, 85, 95 }
```

but that breaks the chain and forces the reader to go backwards.

Is there a way to write the last step:

```
  .reduce((j, k) => { j.add(k); return j }, new Set())
```

in a simpler way using only Javascript builtin functions and without breaking the chain?

Comment: Why do you need the `filter()` and the `map()` when you can do all of it in the `reduce()`?

Comment: @charlietfl Readability for non-toy cases. I'm looking for a way to avoid the long `reduce` if possible. There's `Array.from`, I guess I'm looking for `Array.into` so I could do `[].filter(j => j % 3).map(j => j * 5).into(new Set())` or something like that. Similar to Java's [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) where you can `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Ok but just because the chain might look cool you are creating two extra new arrays and doing more iterations than is necessary

Comment: @charlietfl Point taken about performance. I tend to prefer readability for non-critical pieces of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `j.add(k)` and that will return set itself

> [Set.prototype.add(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add)
>
> Appends value to the Set object. Returns the Set object with added value.

```
[...Array(20).keys()]
  .filter(j => j % 3)
  .map(j => j * 5)
  .reduce((j, k) => j.add(k), new Set())
```

To reduce the steps, you could do all of these in one go, `filter` and `map` could be replace by a `reduce` and 2 `reduce`s could be combine into one (here in your case)

```
[...Array(20).keys()]
  .reduce((j, k) => (k % 3 ? j.add(k * 5) : j), new Set())
```